Is it possible to get the language of the text in a Word Add In using Word JS API?
Is there a way of getting the language of text in a document using the Word JS API for an Office Add In? It seems that the Word.Font class does not have this as an option: link
Is there a work around to getting the selected language? Otherwise, is this something that could be  added in future updates?

If it's not possible via a specific call in the Office-JS API, you could retrieve the OOXML and look at the run properties for each run of text - e.g. "><w:rPr><w:lang w:val="nl-NL"/>...

I feel like this would just be "WORDs" language setting. I would look into some sort of external language JS library. This doesn't need to be office-js API related really IMO.
